# Is it possible to move patches around on the microKorg?

Tags: synthesizer

I've so far just used my microKorg to play around with creating sounds, and am using it for the first time on stage in a few weeks.

When practicing, I've noticed that it's very slow to move between patches that are on different banks, and I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to move my favourite patches around so that I can switch between them very quickly?

Comment: You can copy different timbres: (check page 59) http://inside.massart.edu/Documents/ANImicroKORG_Manual.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Look for the [MicroKorg Sound Editor](http://www.justmusic.de/mall/1/files/if82982Manual_26.pdf). This utility allows you to tweak the parameters of a patch very easily. I can't remember if you can copy/paste entire patches.